# Does the pure motive determine the Voevodsky motive?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motives

I do not quite understand the construction of Voevodsky motives yet. Let $k$ be a field (possibly not algebraically closed), $X$ be a connected smooth projective $k$-scheme. Does the motive of $X$ in the abelian category of pure numerical motives determine its Voevodsky motive? The coefficients are either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ (the answer should address both). Please provide a reference.

Comment: Since the category of Chow motives is a full subcategory of Voevodsky motives, you do not really need the latter here. So, the answer to your question is "yes modulo very difficult conjectures" for rational coefficients, and probably "no" for integral ones.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko oh, Dr. Bondarko himself commenting on my question, this is a lucky day! I have one additional question. I have been told that the Chow motives are not expected to be related to the heart of Voevodsky's category (with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients), while the numerical motives are supposed to be semisimple objects of the heart. How exactly do we embed Chow motives in Voevodsky's motives?

Comment: Heart of what?:) If you speak about the heart of the motivic t-structure then it is very conjectural and not related to any constructions. If you are interested in conjectures then you can read my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0420 or the papers I cite in it. As about your first question: the source is https://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/sites/math.ias.edu.vladimir/files/s5.pdf and arbitrary characteristic is treated in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/motvo.pdf